# Should I package my app into wildfly/jboss modules? (or any Java EE server equivalent tek)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, module, wildfly, jboss7.x

I have taken over a large EE app which was mostly deployed as wildfly/jboss modules. There are separate apps off-course, and then there are this large number of modules.

Now, I get it - the intent is to share these components between multiple apps deployed on your server. But this also tightly couples these modules and to all of these apps. Also, Wildfly/JBoss has the facility to load dependencies from other modules, and each deployment is a module. Why should I package anything into the wildfly/modules/system/layers/base directory? Why not just deploy wars and ears as wildfly/standalone/deployments and define inter-module depdencies there?

What is the best practice? What am I missing here?

Comment: You should never put modules in system directory, this should only be for the containers modules. You can place your own modules in the modules directory, but I would recommend you only do this for utility modules that change infrequently. For example a logging framework or jdbc driver

Comment: Modules can't be hot deployed, so that's one good reason to keep your own code in deployments

Comment: @WillT - to be clear about your first comment - I understood that we should not put modules at all in modules/system, but it is OK to put modules in modules/xxxx as long as they are infrequently changing modules. Did I understand correctly?

Your insights have been much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deploying code in my own deployments allows it to be shared between multiple other deployments and allows for hot deployment.

It is never a good idea place your code within the wildfly system modules.